# Python file - change from CamelCase to underscore naming convention - any way to do it faster?

Tags: python

Few weeks back, in my 4th week of learning python, I have written my first real-life program. Now about a month later, with a little bit more experience in hand, I am trying to refactor the code. First thing I want to do is to change my naming convention to follow the PEP8 guidelines.

Originally I have used a Jupyter Notebook to interactively get the program ready. Since I have come from a Java programming background, using the notebook interface was quite a positive and pleasant surprise as I could inspect the values and code in an interactive manner. Then, once done, I copied and pasted the entire code in a python file and used the Mu Code Editor to run it as a whole.

Now that I am trying to refactor by doing a simple renaming of all the items from a camelCase to underscore convention, both Jupyter and Mu Code Editor did not have any support for refactoring. Hence, after doing a bit of googling, I installed PyCharm and started trying it. The ability to refactor-rename is quite nice, however, I find that it has a number of nuances that I don't fully understand - are there any tips for using renaming so that I could convert all the variables, functions using camelCase to use the underscore convention quickly - for example, all the variables names to be changed in one go, rather than doing it one by one?

Here is the code I am trying to refactor - https://github.com/ssamsudeen/learning-python/blob/master/quranSRS.py

Note: After posting this, I did a bit of experiment to see how Find & Replace works in Jupyter works - Find & Replace dialog had 3 toggle buttons for case sensitivity, regular expressions, and the ability to only replace within selected cells. I found the output it provides to be meaningful - so, this is what I am doing now, till I find a better way to do this. Any suggestion on how I can do Find & Replace better would also be welcome (Ideally, I want the replace to exclude my comments or certain cells, but could not figure out how to do them)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this has to be done with a script, because regular expression string substitution on its own can't change letter case. Here's a Python script to do it:

```py
import sys
import re

with open(sys.argv[1]) as prgm:
    text = prgm.read()
def subfunc(m):
    result = ''
    result += m.group(1)
    # first word
    result += '_'
    result += m.group(2).lower()
    # second word, if present
    if m.group(3):
        result += '_'
        result += m.group(3).lower()
    result += m.group(4)
    return result
text = re.sub(r"(\W?[a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)?(\W|$)", subfunc, text)
with open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as prgm:
    prgm.write(text)
```

Save as `change_caps.py`, run `python change_caps.py quranSRS.py`

Comment: Wow - this is excellent. I have done it manually - let me use your script and try to understand it - this would be another stepping stone in my learning of python. Thank you so much for your help